# How to download the translation modules while installing the app from play store?

Tags: google-mlkit

I am using Flutter and I want to download the translation modules while the app is installed from play store.
Right now the app only downloads the file when a translation is called but I want them to be downloaded with the app to make it offline.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible but please do file [an enhancement request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=897785&template=1457328) with details of your use-case (the latter can help the product management team prioritise the request).

Comment: Btw, it is possible to trigger download of all the language packs you need on first startup of your app, so that the packs are available as soon as possible.